# Website for display list of Json objects

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, frontend, visual-web-developer, google-web-designer

I am purely a back-end developer, I have API server which gives me back List of Json objects over the REST API which I want to display on a webpage. Website design has to be slick and modern. It should also provide different arrangments of displaying the content of Json objects. With this background, is there any website creation platform I can use to hook my API and update my website daily by calling API? Thanks

Comment: yes. there's a dozen of it. you can use react, Vue, angular and another js framework to handle your need. with your question, the answer will so broad. you need to be more specific in order the answer you need the most.

Comment: Well, I wasn't looking for any framework as such. I need sort of CMS like wordpress where I can configure my look and feel of the website and plug in my data which is coming from the API.